# I need help in joining 2 dataframes based on columns of string values

Tags: python, pandas, outer-join

I have 2 dataframes and I need to get a new dataframe based on the outer join of the two, based on the column "name".

| name | total |
| --- | --- |
| aabc | 12 |
| minc | 32 |
| aabd | 34 |
| minc | 45 |
| mini | 40 |

| name | name2 |
| --- | --- |
| minc | bbcs |
| aabc | sddd |
| aabd | mian |
| minc | asda |
| mint | asde |

Output:

| name | name2 | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| minc | bbcs | 32 |
| aabc | sddd | 12 |
| aabd | mian | 34 |
| minc | asda | 45 |
| mini | NaN | 40 |
| mint | asde | NaN |

I have tried to merge them, however in the newdf I have the duplicates of all the names. I can't merge the dfs based on the index because they have different indexes.

```
dfnew=pd.merge(df1, df2, on='name', how='outer')
```

I have also tried to group by "name" the dfnew but the "total" column was showing 0.

```
dfnew.groupby(['name', 'name2']).sum()
```

I have managed to get the wanted result in SQL on IBM Db2 on cloud but I cannot manage to save it to a table or as a csv file.
When I try to use SQL magic in jupyter notebook I get an error that RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOINs are not currently supported

```
%%sql 
select a.name, a.total, b.name2 
from df1 a 
full outer join df2 b 
on a.name=b.name
```

Please help with any ideas or tell me what I'm doing wrong. I do not understand why the merge function does not recognise the strings as being the same in the "name" column. Thank you!

[This is the merged df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbZ6T.png)

[This is how my SQL select table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyqI6.png)

Comment: I'm willing to bet you don't get what you want in SQL with this same data set.  You have duplicates in your merge column, so you should expect every value to match every duplicated value, hence you're getting way more than you thought.

Comment: How are you getting that output? `minc bbcs 12` doesnt make sense to me since the only value associated with 12 is `aabc 12`

Comment: @Chris maybe I did not explain it properly. In SQL I get the wanted result because it identifies which strings from the "name" column are the same, but with the merge function in python it does not. Merging the dfs is giving me the same result as concatenating them and I do not understand why the strings are not recognised as being the same. I'll try to attach some screenshots of my results

Comment: @HenryEcker Sorry, I made a mistake when I wrote the output df

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to somehow get rid of of the conflicting indices.

I would go for:

```
# Saving the indices:
index_1 = df1.index
index_2 = df2.index

# Removing the indices temporarily:
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
# If you index name is 'index'
df1.drop(columns=['index'])
df2.drop(columns=['index'])

# Joing
df1.set_index('name', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('name', inplace=True)
df_joined = df1.join(df2, how=outer, rsuffix='_')

# Adding the indices again
df1['index'] = index_1
df1.set_index('index', inplace=True)

df2['index'] = index_2
df2.set_index('index', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. I have tried to use your code and I get the same result as before (the second df is just appended to the first one, so I get duplicates for the strings that are the same in both dataframes). I have attached the result of the merge in python and the result that I got in SQL by joining the tables, the one that I need.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a temporary column and then use that column for the merege operation.

```
merged_df = (
    df1.assign(t=df1.groupby('name').cumcount()).merge(
        df2.assign(t=df2.groupby('name').cumcount()),
        on=['name', 't'],
        how='outer')
    .drop('t', 1)
)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
   name  total name2
0  aabc   12.0  sddd
1  minc   32.0  bbcs
2  aabd   32.0  mian
3  minc   45.0  asda
4  mini   40.0   NaN
5  mint    NaN  asde
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have used the code that you have shared, however I still got the same result as before (the second df is just appended to the first one, so I get duplicates for the strings that are the same in both dataframes). I do not know why the strings are not identified as being the same.

Comment: @elenamutescu what's your expected output? I guess my code is matching with the expected output that you posted above.